# Converting table to raw binary/hex file

Tags: audio, text, wav, waveform

So, I managed to get a text output from simulator of this form:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

... and need to convert all the integers to two-byte binary words for .wav format, so every number represents a sample. Little Endian mode is necessary.

I tried to do that with Notepad++, but failed. Presence of NL chatracters may be confusing for some buil-in plugins, but can't merge numbers before they have right lenght.

I would be very thankful for any trick to do that easily.
Thanks in advance.